# Concourse CI: static_buildpack issue

Tags: concourse

I am deploying a simple angular4 application to cloud foundry using static_buildpack. While accessing the application I am always getting nginx 403 issue.

```
jobs:
- name: app
  serial: true
  plan:
  - get: develop-repo
  - task: npm-build
    config:
        platform: linux
        image_resource:
            type: docker-image
            source:
                repository: node
        run:
            path: sh
            args:
            - -exec
            - |
                cd develop-repo
                npm install
                npm run dist                              
        inputs:
        - name: develop-repo
        outputs:
        - name:
  - put: develop
    params:
      manifest: develop-repo/manifest.yml
      current_app_name: app   
      path: develop-repo        



resources:
- name: develop-repo
  type: git
- name: develop
  type: cf
```

manifest.yml:

```
---
applications:
- name: app
  instances: 1
  memory: 512M
  disk_quota: 512M  
  buildpack: staticfile_buildpack 
  stack: cflinuxfs2
```

All I am doing is `git clone -> npm build -> cf deploy`

**Note**: All resource variables are rightly set. Just ignored for better readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out couple of options, I found that by publishing the artifacts to the output folder we can push the app from the output folder

```
---
jobs:
- name: app
  serial: true
  plan:
  - get: develop
  - task: npm-build
    config:
        platform: linux
        image_resource:
            type: docker-image
            source:
                repository: node
        inputs:
        - name: develop
        outputs:
        - name: artifacts
        run:
            path: sh
            args:
            - -exec
            - |
                cd develop
                npm install
                npm run dist
                ls
                cp -R dist ../artifacts/                            

  - put: deploy-cf
    params:
        manifest: develop/ci/manifests/manifest-int.yml
        path: artifacts/dist


resources:
- name: develop
  type: git
  source:
    uri: <<GITHUB-URI>>
    branch:<<GITHUB-BRANCH>>
    username:<<GITHUB-USERNAME>>
    password: <<GITHUB-PASSWORD>>
- name: deploy-cf
  type: cf
  source:
    api: <<CF-API>>
    username: <<CF-USERNAME>>
    password: <<CF-PASSWORD>>
    organization: <<CF-ORG>>
    space: <<CF-SPACE>>
```